# How can ı do vue 3 compositon api router refresh page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, primevue

After confirming in vue 3 compositon api

`router.push('/IssueList');`

Here, I want my  and  components to refresh when they come to the IssueList page.

I'm redirecting to the page, but it doesn't refresh the issuelist page. How can I do that?

The codes on my IssueList page are as follows.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="card">
      
      <h5>Konu Listesi</h5>
      <Button label="Yeni Konu Oluştur" class="p-button-success p-button-outlined mb-2" icon="pi pi-plus"
              @click="newIssue"></Button>
      <TabView ref="tabview1">
        <TabPanel header="Bana Gelenler">
          <issue-incoming></issue-incoming>
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel header="Benim Yazdıklarım">
          <issue-send  ></issue-send>
        </TabPanel>
      </TabView>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly you should tie a :key value pair to the component you want to refresh. so essentially when whatever happens in the example function it will increment the change variable which is tied to the component and forces it to refresh.

example -

```
    <template>
  <div>
   <div @click="example()"> <p>update</p> </div>
    <Component :key="change" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Component,
  },
  setup() {
    var change = ref(0);

    function example() {
      
        change.value += 1;
      
    }

    return {
      change,
      example,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Where do I call the example function? So where do I need to trigger this function?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that bit too. You could put it in the @click="newIssue, example()" or you could call it in the end of the newIssue function assuming it's a function.

Comment: Actually, if newIssue is a function you could forgo the example function all together and just put the change.value += 1 at the end of the newIssue function. I'm just guessing here since I don't know what the rest of your code looks like